# EF Core LINQ Where with extension methods are not translated to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Given the following query:

```
context.ToolingOrders
.Include(r => r.ToolingOrderDetails)
.Include(r => r.PurchaseOrder)
.Where(r => r.VendorId.EqualsOrNull(filter.VendorId) && 
            r.PoNumber.ContainsOrEmpty(filter.PoNumber))
```

I use these extension methods to save some code:

```
 public static class FilterExtensions
 {
        public static bool ContainsOrEmpty(this string source, string toCheck)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toCheck) || source?.IndexOf(toCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }

        public static bool EqualsOrNull(this int source, int? toCheck)
        {
            return !toCheck.HasValue || source == toCheck;
        }
 }
```

The problem is, due to these extension methods, the Where part is not translated into SQL.

I use .Net Core 2.2, which has this [client side evaluation feature](https://elanderson.net/2019/01/entity-framework-core-client-side-evaluation/), which totally hides this issue, but the SQL profiler shows it anyway.

Is there any way to make this work, or I have to write every piece of the where part explicitly?

Comment: @Train Are you sure that's the link you meant to post?

Comment: FYI, when using LInq that is translated to SQL the case sensitivity of string comparisons will be determined by the collation of the DB (which is usually case insensitive)

Comment: @juharr Good to know, but we still have to handle the case if the filter value is null, then don't filter it.

Comment: Sorry for some reason it was the wrong link

Comment: Your issue is that your mixing client side expressions that don't translate to sql queries. I know it's going to be a longer road but, I would suggest either fully reconstructing the queries so they can be translated to SQL or pull them into memory and then filter with those operations. If this continues you're going to have a harder time in the future. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: I know what I posted was for EF core 3, but it's most likely the best way to go but also the biggest head ache.

Comment: Eventually, I rewrote my code without extensions and helpers, everything is explicitly coded into the Where clause, now it is properly translated into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `IQueryable` for your specific object.
Take the following object for instance:

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyProperty;
}
```

You could write an extension like this:

```cs
public static class MyQueryExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<MyObject> WhereMyPropertyNull(this IQueryable<MyObject> queryable)
    {
        return queryable.Where(obj => obj.MyProperty == null);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
var queryable = new List<MyObject>().AsQueryable();
var result = queryable.WhereMyPropertyNull().ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Based on some feedback i updated my answer to handle generics.

```cs
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TEntity> EqualOrNull<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, Func<TEntity, TProperty> selector, TProperty match)
        {
            return source.Where(entity => Match(selector.Invoke(entity), match));
        }

        private static bool Match<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity entity, TProperty match)
        {
            if (entity == null) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return entity.Equals(match);
            }
        }
    }
```

It can be used to pass the value of a property to the where statement:

```cs
            var list = new List<MyObject>();
            list.Add(new MyObject {MyProperty = "Test"});
            list.Add(new MyObject {MyProperty = "NoMatch"});
            list.Add(new MyObject {MyProperty = null});

            var result = list.AsQueryable()
                .EqualOrNull(o => o.MyProperty, "Test")
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I use these methods for totally different entities, in 30 different queries, so this does not help much I think.

Comment: This could be made generic by passing in a `Expression<Func<TEntity, TProp>>` to select the column to compare to null.

Comment: I think that complicates the things more than simplify it. Just inspect my problem again, and you will see, that your solution doesn't solve my problem. Consider the following: we have a User entity with an Email field, we would like to filter it as well in a different place, how would you do it with one generic expression? There is nothing common in user and Toolingorder...

Comment: I've just tried this approach, and it looks a good idea, but EF still does not translate this to SQL, executes the Where part on client side. Here is the profiled SQL query, there is no where clause: SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[BillTo], [r].[CreateDate]
FROM [ToolingOrder] AS [r]
LEFT JOIN [PurchaseOrders] AS [r.PurchaseOrder] ON [r].[PurchaseOrderId] = [r.PurchaseOrder].[Id]
ORDER BY [r].[CreateDate] DESC, [r].[Id]